# Clear chat input box only for sender in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hi I am making a online chatting app for all the person but when I send the message the chat input box is clear to everyone and I want to clear the chat input box only from sender
I use this code in client.js to clear the chat input box but it clear from all the user browser

```
chatInputBox.innerHTML = "";
```

if anyone writing a message in chat box and another one send the message the chat input box is clear to everyone

is there is any solution of socket.io to solve this problem

Comment: not clear what you are saying

Answer (score 1):

That means that text is sent to everyone even to sender himself,
the way foward is on you're `node.js` server use `socket.broadcast` to send a message
so you dont need even to clear the inbox since sender wont even receive his own message

the code is `socket.broadcast.emit("event_name", "message data - could be object");`

Comment: Try and send you're section of code on sending and ui codes just an area you're talking about, then we could be very clear on what to do